# Use of extern in translation unit

Tags: c, extern, linkage

```
extern int a;
int a = 1;

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Is this UB? standard says in 6.2.2/7

If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external
linkage, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly defined behavior. And this is what the compiler would get after pre-processing after an header is included.

Your confusion seems to come that:

```
int a = 1;
```

has not internal linkage. At file-scope `a` has external linkage. It would have internal linkage if the `static` specifier was added.

Answer (score 5):

The default linkage *is* `extern`. The `extern` specifier indicates that it might be defined and initialized in another translation unit, or the same one. The relative placement of an `extern` declaration does not matter, or they would be somewhat dangerous.

C99 TC2 §6.9.2/1

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the declaration is an external definition for the identifier.

This is followed by an example:

```
int i1 = 1;  // definition, external linkage
…
extern int i1;  // refers to previous, whose linkage is external
```

Comment: Is the C++11-standard really relevant for a 'C' question?

Comment: @junix. Didn't notice. I'll look it up in the other standard, but this is an area where they're generally compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no.

If `a` is defined elsewhere in the same translation unit then yes, it's undefined behaviour.

If `a` is not defined anywhere else then `int a=1`; will be considered as the *external* definition of `a` (despite being defined in the same file). So it's not undefined.

Answer (score -2):

Yes I think this will lead to (toolchain dependent) behaviour. Why?

The compiler generates a (for the linker) visible symbol 'a' while translating code like `int a = ...;`. The line `extern int a;` tells the compiler that every reference to 'a' will be be resolved by the linker.

This leaves two possible ways the compiler handles this contradiction: 
 1. By chance (as you only have one visible symbol called 'a') the linker binds the references to the created symbol 'a' of the same translation unit.
 2. The compiler ignores the extern statement and binds directly to the a of this compilation unit.

An 'internal' symbol has to be declared as static (`static int a = ...;`) and then you'll get your UB i think.

Comment: The compiler can't do things nearly that greedily. The TUs are translated with internal references resolved from beginning to end, then they are merged.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Of course the compiler could do this. Although you might be right, that a proper implementation will link all occurencies of 'a' extern and let the linker do the job.